# How is the literature of the Beat Generation considered in academia, by literature experts?

Tags: reception

How is the literature of the Beat Generation considered in the academia, by literature experts?

For instance, is it considered as a major movement, or a minor one?
Kerouac wanted to become the new Proust: are his writings seen as good as Proust’s?

Beat Generation:

> The Beat Generation was a literary subculture movement started by a
> group of authors whose work explored and influenced American culture
> and politics in the post-war era.[1] The bulk of their work was
> published and popularized by Silent Generationers in the 1950s, better
> known as Beatniks. The central elements of Beat culture are the
> rejection of standard narrative values, making a spiritual quest, the
> exploration of American and Eastern religions, the rejection of
> economic materialism, explicit portrayals of the human condition,
> experimentation with psychedelic drugs, and sexual liberation and
> exploration.[2][3]
>
> Allen Ginsberg's Howl (1956), William S. Burroughs' Naked Lunch
> (1959), and Jack Kerouac's On the Road (1957) are among the best known
> examples of Beat literature.

(Wikipedia)

Comment: I think there's an interesting question here - I've been pondering some of these issues myself - but IMO right now this is a bit broad. Can you focus it a bit on particular aspects of how beat literature is studied in academia?

Comment: @Thanks. What do you mean by “how it is studied”?

Comment: I don't know - that's kind of the problem with your question. I don't know what it is you want to uncover here?

Comment: I mean (1) how experts and professors of, say, English literature, or European comparative literature, who also, by means of general culture, personal culture, or particular expertise, consider this literary movement (2) with time passing and many journalistic and academic investigation of this literature, what is currently the view on its quality and its legacy’s importance

Comment: It is not rare that in papers introduction or in encyclopedic articles concerning one literary movement, it is recalled what it the general view held on the legacy and quality of a movement

Comment: What is the quality and the legacy of the beat generation with regard to the history of Western literature? It is for instance no doubt that French realism or German romanticism are considered major literary movements with regard to both their influence and their quality

Comment: Maybe French realism is considered relatively less important **with regard to** German romanticism, btw

Comment: Well for me your (1) and (2) are too broad. But hey, it's got an upvote, so what do I know?

Comment: @MattThrower haha, we’ll see. I will reflect on it and think if I can make it clearer

Comment: I hope you can. It's struck me that there's definitely a disconnect in the way the beats are treated as a conscious literary movement when compared to both the size and rigour of the modernist and postmodernist movements that bookend them. I suspect it's because they had an outsized impact on the popular cultural landscape of the US.

Comment: “ It's struck me that there's definitely a disconnect in the way the beats are treated as a conscious literary movement when compared to both the size and rigour of the modernist and postmodernist movements that bookend them.” I am not sure what you mean by disconnect, but my feeling is that the beat generation is not treated as a very legitimate artistic movement.

Comment: To take a comparable example, the European seems to me to be taken much more seriously. It is taught in French junior high and high school for instance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143084/discussion-between-starckman-and-matt-thrower).

Comment: This might plausibly be considered a [scholarly entry-point](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1704/scholarly-entry-point-questions-should-be-on-topic-and-not-considered-recomme) question.

Comment: I think even "considered in academia" is too broad.  There may be literary historians who don't count Beat literature as an important movement, but a quick Google search turned up evidence that there are courses being taught on the subject at Columbia, University of Chicago, Berkeley, U Penn, Yale, etc.  The fact that these courses exist means that some academics think the topic is worth studying.  But there's no reason to expect there to be any consensus on a question like, "was Kerouac as good as Proust."

Comment: @Juhasz Thank you for these information. "But there's no reason to expect there to be any consensus on a question like, "was Kerouac as good as Proust."" But I think there is a consensus Proust was in the top 5, if not 3, of the major writers of the 19th century, if not history!